# Get case class parameter types as a HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to generate instances of case class using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

This works for generating instances of `Foo`

```
case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)

class Context {
  val random = new Random()
}

def genInt(context: Context): Int = {
  context.random.nextInt()
}

def genString(context: Context): String = {
  context.random.nextString(16)
}

object ClassesToGenerators extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt = at[Class[Int]](_ => genInt(_))
  implicit def caseString = at[Class[String]](_ => genString(_))
}


val gen = Generic[Foo]
val context = new Context()
val classes = classOf[Int] :: classOf[String] :: HNil // can't figure out how to get this hlist programmatically
val generators = classes.map(ClassesToGenerators)

gen.from(generators.zipApply(generators.mapConst(context)))
```

However, I'm aiming to write something reusable like

```
def newInstance[T] -> T:
  ???
```

which could generate instances of any case classes that takes only int and string parameters.

As mentioned in the code snippet, I'm stuck at getting a hlist of case class attribute types i.e. would like to convert `case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)` to `classOf[Int] :: classOf[String] :: HNil`. Any other approaches to this problem are also very appreciated but I'm not looking for a generic way of generating random instances of cases classes (as my use-case is different and used random generator just as an example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, **Shapeless** is better used when you forget about all the fancy stuff and just focus on simple typeclass derivation using `HList` like this:

```scala
import shapeless.{Generic, HList, HNil, :: => :!:}
import scala.util.Random

trait Context {
  def random: Random
}
object Context {
  object implicits {
    implicit final val global: Context = new Context {
      override final val random: Random = new Random() 
    }
  }
}

trait Generator[A] {
  def generate(context: Context): A
}
object Generator {
  final def apply[A](implicit ev: Generator[A]): ev.type = ev
  
  final def generate[A](implicit ev: Generator[A], ctx: Context): A =
    ev.generate(ctx)
  
  implicit final val IntGenerator: Generator[Int] =
    new Generator[Int] {
      override def generate(context: Context): Int =
        context.random.nextInt()
    }
  
  implicit final val StringGenerator: Generator[String] =
    new Generator[String] {
      override def generate(context: Context): String =
        context.random.nextString(16)
    }
  
  implicit final def auto[P <: Product](implicit ev: GeneratorGen[P]): Generator[P] = ev
}

sealed trait GeneratorRepr[R <: HList] extends Generator[R]
object GeneratorRepr {
  implicit final val HNilGeneratorRepr: GeneratorRepr[HNil] =
    new GeneratorRepr[HNil] {
      override def generate(context: Context): HNil =
        HNil
    }
  
  implicit final def HConsGeneratorRepr[E, T <: HList](
    implicit ev: Generator[E], tail: GeneratorRepr[T]
  ): GeneratorRepr[E :!: T] =
    new GeneratorRepr[E :!: T] {
      override def generate(context: Context): E :!: T =
        ev.generate(context) :: tail.generate(context)
    }
}

sealed trait GeneratorGen[P <: Product] extends Generator[P]
object GeneratorGen {
  implicit final def instance[P <: Product, R <: HList](
    implicit gen: Generic.Aux[P, R], ev: GeneratorRepr[R]
  ): GeneratorGen[P] = new GeneratorGen[P] {
    override def generate(context: Context): P =
      gen.from(ev.generate(context))
  }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
import Context.implicits.global

final case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)

val result = Generator.generate[Foo]
// result: Foo = Foo(-2127375055, "鞰Ϗƨ⹼沺㗝䚮Ⴍ욏ꖱꬮӝ闉믃雦峷")
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/CnZXHk2YTgqJjxQlsqbLrw/4)*.

Comment: Forgetting "all the fancy stuff" can be sometimes less optimal :)

Answer (score 3):

Using built-in Shapeless type classes you can do

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.FillWith
import shapeless.{Generic, HList, Poly0}

val context = new Context()

object ClassesToGenerators extends Poly0 {
  implicit val caseInt = at[Int](genInt(context))
  implicit val caseString = at[String](genString(context))
}

def newInstance[A] = new PartiallyApplied[A]

class PartiallyApplied[A] {
  def apply[L <: HList]()(implicit
    generic: Generic.Aux[A, L],
    fillWith: FillWith[ClassesToGenerators.type, L]
  ): A = generic.from(fillWith())
}

newInstance[Foo]() // Foo(2018031886,⮐掐禃惌ᰧ佨妞꨸ዤࠒ훿柲籐妭蝱⻤)
```